# SMAATO showing same AD every time and also not considering CLICKS : AIR For Android AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, click, ads

Anyone has integrated smaato ads in AIR for Android apps? I have done it, everything is working fine in test mode. but when I uses my app ID it ll give same ads every time, and on clicking it, its navigate to browser with one url but its blank. One more thing smaato still showing 0 click even I clicked for testing purpose. Anyone has the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting in a support ticket via the publisher portal, but this mostly likely has to do with how your app is providing the user agent. There are no "clicks" because you're not using the same information (IP address and user agent) as the ad request so the system is flagging it as "fraud".

As mentioned above, if you put in a ticket and provide the publisher ID and adspace ID of the property in question, we can do a further analysis.

Regards